# Problemas com lógica (&& ou ||)

Tags: c#, .net, operadores

Achei estranho o código que está em meu sistema:

```
if (cmbCdTipoProcesso.SelectedValue != "3" && cmbCdTipoProcesso.SelectedValue != "4")    
{....}
```

Aparentemente o código está estranho, pois eu nunca vou ter `cmbCdTipoProcesso.SelectedValue = 3` ou `cmbCdTipoProcesso.SelectedValue = 4` e assim por diante, aí eu pensei: Então porque a lógica AND e não a OR?

Voltando para eletrônica, tratando de álgebra booleana, numa lógica AND eu tenho uma saída 1 quando todas as entradas forem 1, caso o contrário a saída será sempre 0, mas aplicando à programação.

Parece que a situação nunca vai acontecer ou eu estou errado? Situação do `if`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Leia de novo olhando caractere por caractere. Sua leitura do código, de acordo com a explicação que você escreveu abaixo dele está levando em consideração que está vendo se ambos são **iguais** a 3 e 4 ao mesmo tempo. De fato isto é impossível acontecer.

O problema é que o código está verificando se ambos são **diferentes** de 3 e 4. E isto é perfeitamente possível.

OU seja, este código está pegando qualquer valor exceto os que sejam 3 e 4.

Por alguma razão o código precisa que excluir estes valores. Não sei se é óbvio porque precisa desconsiderar estes valores para a ação. Por isto é importante comentar código, ou melhor ainda, escrever código que mostre porque está fazendo isso.

Neste caso estaria errado se usasse o `||` já que sempre daria verdadeiro. Assim como um número nunca pode ser igual a outro diferente, um número sempre será diferente de outro.

Fiz uma tabela de resultados tentando fazer diversas comparações com a mesma variável e valores diferentes.

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var x = 1;
        WriteLine(x == 1 || x == 2);
        WriteLine(x == 1 || x != 2);
        WriteLine(x != 1 || x != 2);
        WriteLine(x == 1 && x == 2);
        WriteLine(x == 1 && x != 2);
        WriteLine(x != 1 && x != 2);
        WriteLine(x == 3 || x == 2);
        WriteLine(x == 3 || x != 2);
        WriteLine(x != 3 || x != 1);
        WriteLine(x == 3 && x == 2);
        WriteLine(x == 3 && x != 2);
        WriteLine(x != 3 && x != 2);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Kqdfw8). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PMbPlJ). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Operator/Relational.cs).

Comment: Perfeito Bigown, perfeito. Isso vai provar que o cara está errado e posso trabalhar como está. O programador antes de mim está correto. Há muitas críticas ao cara e eu não vim aqui para isso, por isso vou provar que o colega anterior estava correto.

Comment: @pnet Se eles possuem tempo para criticar (erroneamente) álgebra booleana e micro-gerenciar código assim, eu diria que o problema é de gestão, não de implementação.

Answer (score 3):

É muito mais fácil resolver este problema matematicamente, simplesmente substituindo os teus longos nomes de variáveis com letras tipo `A` ou `B`, substituindo o símbolo `&&` com um simples `and` ou `AND` ou `e`, (e ignorando, por motivos práticos, que "3" e "4" são *strings*). No teu caso temos:

```
cmbCdTipoProcesso.SelectedValue != "3" && cmbCdTipoProcesso.SelectedValue != "4"
```

Que traduzido mais simplesmente quer dizer:

```
A != 3 e A != 4
```

Ou seja:

```
A é diferente de 3 e A é diferente de 4
```

1. Supõe `A` é 3.

   Vamos là valutar a expressão:

   `A é diferente de 3 e A é diferente de 4`

   A expressão em cima vai ser valutada *falsa*, porque `A = 3`, mesmo que `A != 4`.
2. Se `A` fosse 4, seriamos na mesma situação.
3. Só no caso em que `A` é diferente **ao mesmo tempo** de 3 e 4 é que o bloco do teu `if` vai ser executado.

---

Num caso mais geral, onde tempos `A` e `B` a ser valutados:

```
if A != 3 e B != 4
```

ou seja, segundo uma das leis de [*De Morgan*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws):

```
if !(A == 3 ou B == 4)
```

ou seja, em português:

```
se não (A igual a 3 ou B igual a 4)
```

Ou seja o bloco do `if` vai ser executado quando a situação entre parêntesis é **falsa** (*porque a negação de falso é verdadeiro*), ou seja todos os casos em que *A é diferente de 3* e *B é diferente de 4* **ao mesmo tempo**, por exemplo:

```
A = 2 // A é diferente de 3
B = 7 // B é diferente de 4
```

Se *A é igual a 3* ou *B é igual a 4*, ou os dois, a expressão do `if` não vai ser considerada verdadeira. Repito, `A` tem que ser diferente de 3 e `B` tem que ser diferente de 4, se não o bloco do `if` não vai ser executado.

Answer (score 2):

O que esse trecho nos diz é que o valor selecionado deve ser `diferente de 3` `E` `diferente de 4`.

Lembrando que o operador lógico `!=` significa diferença e não igualdade.

Uma outra forma de escrever a mesma lógica seria igual a: `valor < 3 && valor > 4`,são duas maneiras diferentes de construir a mesma roda....

Quanto a outra dúvida de lógica booleana, eu não entendi aonde você quis chegar, poderia explicar melhor?

**--EDIT**, o que o @Maniero disse está correto, a utilização do `||` nesse caso seria equivocado, porque tiraria a unicidade da condição.

Comment: Tá difícil fazer o chefe entender isso aqui. O raciocínio dele está ao contrário.

Comment: kkk @pnet, o que está feito, está feito, a lógica é so uma, não adianta seu chefe querer entender 'a' por 'b', isso não é problema na programação, e sim no bom senso

Comment: VB e C# são linguagens completamente diferente, mas a lógica condicional é igual nas duas kk

Comment: Na condição a única diferença que teria, é que enquanto em C# diferente é equivalente a `!=`, em VB diferente é equivalente a `<>`